# Modifying this PHP snippet: Show this only to users that belong to role X, AND does not belong to role Y

Tags: php

I´ve got this PHP snippet that allows me to show the tabs only to authenticated users.
How do I modify this to show only if it does belong to that role, but does NOT belong to role X?

```
<?php global $user; 
if (is_array($user->roles) && in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) {?> 
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
          <div id="content-tabs" class=""><?php print $tabs; ?></div><!-- /#content-tabs -->
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I know that maybe it should contain something like an **elseif**, and the negative **!** sign. But how do I do that?
Thanks for your help!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`!` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if (is_array($user->roles) &&
    in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles) &&
    !in_array('role X', $user->roles)) { ... }
```